# Hbase require password to start

Tags: hbase

I am trying to run Hbase with `./start-hbase.sh` command inside bin directory. It requires password. Can anyone guide me which password it require here?

```
haider@localhost's password:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those start scripts work by using `ssh` to connect to your worker machines, to start the local services there.

The password it is asking for is your (ssh) login password.  This is probably because you either have not generated a public key for yourself, or you have not added it to your own `authorized_keys` file.